# pad leading zero to BC year in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am converting a negative numeric to a BC date using the Lubridate package, I want to add the initial 0 to three or two digits year.
Here is an example:

```
library(lubridate)
lubridate::as_date(-836404) #note that the number is negative for BC
```

result gives

```
"-320-01-02"
```

But I want it to give

```
"-0320-01-02"
```

I want to keep it as a date.
Any suggestion?